# Finding closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^n k2^{k-1}$

Tags: summation

I am trying to use the perturbation method to find a closed form for:

$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k2^{k-1}
$$

This is what I’ve tried so far:

$$
S_n + (n+1)2^n = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} k2^{k-1}
$$

$$
S_n + (n+1)2^n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^{k}
$$

$$
S_n + (n+1)2^n = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k2^{k-1}
$$

$$
S_n + (n+1)2^n = 1 + 0 + n2^{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} k2^{k-1}
$$

But I don’t think it is right since it would result in a $S_n - S_n = ...$

Could you please help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know calculus? I think that may be helpful here.

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by "use the perturbation method"? You seem not to be using it in what you've tried so far.

Comment: Through the perturbation method we have to get the first and add a last element to the summation. I believe that was what I did, didn’t I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the mistake: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^{k}\ne \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k2^{k-1}$.

Here is the right way:
$$\begin{align}S_n + (n+1)2^n &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^{k}=\\
&=1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+2)2^{k+1}=\\
&=1+\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k\cdot 2^{k+1}}+\color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{k+2}}=\\
&=1+\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot 2^{k+1}-n\cdot 2^{n+1}}+\color{red}{4(2^n-1)}=\\
&=1+4\sum_{k=0}^nk\cdot 2^{k-1}-n\cdot 2^{n+1}+4(2^n-1)=\\
&=1+4S_n-n\cdot 2^{n+1}+4(2^n-1) \Rightarrow \\
3S_n&=(n+1)2^n-1+n\cdot 2^{n+1}-4(2^n-1)=\\
&=3n\cdot 2^n-3\cdot 2^n+3 \Rightarrow \\
S_n&=n\cdot 2^n-2^n+1.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help @farruhota. I have a question though. In the first line you wrote 

$$
\begin{align}S_n + (n+1)2^n &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)2^{k}=\\
\end{align}
$$

Since you added one more element in the left side, shouldn't you change the indexes $k$ and $n$ in the right side? So it would become 

$$
\begin{align}S_n + (n+1)2^n &= 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} (k+1)2^{k}=\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: No. The two lines of your trial are correct. The mistake occurred in the third line, which I specified in my answer. Remember, $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk2^{k-1}$. So on the left side: $S_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k2^{k−1}=S_n+(n+1)2^{n+1−1}=S_n+(n+1)2^n$ and on the right side: $S_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k2^{k−1}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k2^{k−1}=1+\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)2^k=⋯$. So, check again.

Comment: I got your point. Thank you very much for the patience and very detailed explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. In fact, you defended (succeeded in) your own method. Good luck.

Comment: I am sorry to disturb you again with this, but I did't get how you got from the line 4 to line 5. Specifically,  how 
$$1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n} k \cdot 2 ^{k+1}$$
became 
$$1 + 4 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n} k \cdot 2 ^{k-1}$$
My question is how the constant $4$ appeared there and how the exponent $k+1$ became $k-1$. Thank you very much.

Comment: note: $\sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot 2^{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot 2^{k-1+2}=\sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot 2^{k-1}\cdot 2^2=2^2\sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot 2^{k-1}$.

Comment: You are my hero! I am out of words! Thank you very very much!

Comment: no problem. it is good to see your eager to practice and understand.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k2^{k-1}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k-1}\right)+\left(\sum_{k=2}^n 2^{k-1}\right)+\ldots
$$
and every sum in parentheses is easy to compute. (And the sum of them also).

Comment: It seems that you replaced $k2^{k-1}$ by $2^{k-1}$ inside the parentheses. Is that right? That $k$ would not change the final result?

Comment: @DiegoMarques The trick is based on $n=1+1+\ldots1$ ($n$ times), leading to geometric sequences, with known sums.

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k 2^{k-1}=1\cdot 2^0 +2\cdot 2^1+3\cdot 2^2+\cdots+n2^{n-1}=$$
$$=\big(2^0+2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^{n-1}\big)+\big(1\cdot 2^1+2\cdot 2^2+\cdots+(n-1)2^{n-1}\big)=\quad (*)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k+2\big(1\cdot 2^0+2\cdot 2^1+\cdots+(n-1)2^{n-2}\big)=\quad (**)$$
$$=(2^n-1)+2 S_{n-1}.$$

So,
$$S_n=(2^n-1)+2(S_n-n2^{n-1}).$$

And you can get $S_n$ from there.

---

(*) I'm using the fact that if I have
$$1\cdot 2^0+2\cdot 2^1+3\cdot 2^2+4\cdot 2^3+\cdots,$$
that means that I have $2^0$ once, $2^1$ added twice, $2^2$ added three times, $2^3$ four times, and so on. So next I took just one of each to form the sum
$$2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+\cdots$$
and the original sum ends up whith one less $2^0$ (that is, with none), one less $2^1$ (so just only one), one less $2^2$ (just two), one less $2^3$ (just three, instead of the original four), etc.

Let's put it backwards: if you sum
$$2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+\cdots$$
and
$$[0\cdot 2^0]+[1]\cdot 2^1 +2\cdot 2^2 +3\cdot 2^3+\cdots$$
(I put between squared brackets what you wouldn't usually type explicitly),
you would get the original
$$1\cdot 2^0+2\cdot 2^1+3\cdot 2^2+4\cdot 2^3+\cdots.$$

(**) Now, going back to the decomposition in two sums we've got: I finally took out a common factor $2$ from the second sum to get back all terms in which the exponent of the $2$ is one less than the coefficient by which it is multiplied, which caracterizes the terms of $S_n$.

---

Notes:

The answer is, naturally,
$$S_n=1-2^n+n2^n=1+(n-1)2^n.$$

This is a perturbation process, since I wrote $S_n$ in terms of $S_{n-1}$, from which I made $S_n$ reappear. I could have started from $S_{n+1}$, too, and reduce it to an expression on $S_n$, like in
$$S_{n+1}=2^{n+1}-1+2S_n.$$
Then I could have gone on like
$$S_n+(n+1)2^n=2^{n+1}-1+2S_n,$$
and the same result would arise from this equation.

Comment: Thank you. I just didn’t understand exactly how you got the second and third lines. Could you explain it?

Comment: I hope the explanation marked with $(*)$ will be of some help. Ask me, otherwise.

Comment: That is perfect. It is totally clear now. Thank you very very much for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $n$, and define a function
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nx^k$$
Note that for $x\neq 1$:
$$f(x)(1-x)=x-x^{n+1}$$
hence, for $x\neq 1$:
$$f(x)=\frac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Now differentiate $f$:

$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}$$
but also:

$$f'(x)=\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}$$

so we deduce that for every $x\neq 1$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}=\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}$$

In particular, for $x=2$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk2^{k-1}=2^nn-2^n+1$$